# how to read property of undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript

Not sure what i am doing wrong here.
it doesn't give me result.

```
var dd= function(name){
    this.sayHello=function(){

        alert ("hello " + this.ss);
    }
    this.name=name;
}

dd("jack").sayHello();
```

Am i calling it correctly? what is best tool to debug js

Comment: Your first step should be to indent your code consistently and readably. That will help a lot.

Comment: `new dd("jack").sayHello();` read about new operator if you want to understand why.

Comment: To know what you are doing, first you must understand what `this` means in your code. `this` means totally different things when the containing function is called differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `dd` function:

1. Never creates an object
2. Never returns anything from `dd`
3. Refers to two different properties (`name` and `ss`), setting up one but using the other

Your call to your `dd` function seems to expect it to create and return an object, and seems to expect `sayHello` to use the same property that `dd` sets up (`name`).

So:

```js
var dd = function(name) {
  return {
    sayHello: function() {
      alert("hello " + this.name);
    },
    name: name
  };
};
dd("Jack").sayHello();
```

Alternately, if you want to use the `new` keyword, you could do this:

```js
var Dd = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.sayHello = function() {
    alert("hello " + this.name);
  };
};
new Dd("Jack").sayHello();
```

With `new`, the object is created by the `new` operator, and the result of the `new Dd(...)` expression is the object `new` created (unless `Dd` returns a different object instead).

Note that I capitalized the first letter. This is the overwhelming convention with constructor functions (functions you call via `new`) in JavaScript.

You can also move `sayHello` to the object that will get assigned as the prototype of the object created by `new`. The object that gets assigned as the prototype is available on the `DD.prototype` property, so:

```js
var Dd = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
};
Dd.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  alert("hello " + this.name);
};
new Dd("Jack").sayHello();
```

> what is best tool to debug js

All modern browsers have fully-featured debuggers built in. They're usually available by pressing F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I, or of course from the browser's menus or [hamburger button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button). Which one you use is totally up to you. I quite like the Dev Tools in Chrome.